# how to show the image after I use Image.fromarry() on the pyqt4

Tags: opencv, pyqt, python-imaging-library

I use cv2 and pil module to edit a image

```
image =  cv2.medianBlur(img_gray, 7)
image = Image.fromarray(image)
```

how can I show the image on the pyqt4?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
def pil2pixmap(self,im):
    if im.mode == "RGB":
        pass
    #elif im.mode =="L":
        #im = im.convert("RGBA")
    data = im.convert("RGBA").tostring("raw","RGBA")
    qim = QtGui.QImage(data, im.size[0], im.size[1], QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
    return pixmap
```

and it works.